# create environment variables based on the webpack entry point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, tree-shaking

I am splitting my react code with multiple entry points in webpack, these bundles are then loaded independently at completely different pages(HTML documents).

I have a lot of shared code, and most of my shared logic is under `if-else` check, so this shared logic is present in all the bundles, causing the increase in bundle size.
The condition for this `if-else` check is based on a variable which we generate at run time, but these variables can be set based on the entrypoint.

Is it possible to set some environment variable based on entrypoints(which I can use for the `if-else` check), so webpack can treeshake and remove the code which is not required in the bundle?

Answer (score 3):

I had a more less similar issue on my project. We needed to have different builds for different products and of course wanted to omit irrelevant code in the bundle. Might be you find something useful here

### Step 1 - Create new build definitions with variables

```
{
 scripts: {
  "build:first": "SET TYPE=first && npm run build",
  "build:second": "SET TYPE=second && npm run build"
 }
}
```

Note - I am using `SET SOME_VARIABLE=XXXX` to provide environment variable for the build

### Step 2 Split your shared file into several files:

/shared/first.tsx

```
export const firstMethod = () => "I AM A FIRST";
```

/shared/second.tsx

```
export const secondMethod = () => "I AM A SECOND";
```

### Step 3 - update your imports and point them to the specific files

// first.tsx

```
import { firstMethod } from "./shared/first";
export default () => <> First Component says: {firstMethod()}  </>;
```

// second.tsx

```
import { secondMethod } from "./shared/second";
export default () => <> Second Component says: {secondMethod()} </>;
```

### Final Step - Use If-Else, Environmental variable and React.lazy to load your entry point

```
let LazyComponent: React.LazyExoticComponent<() => JSX.Element>;

if (process.env.TYPE === "first") {
  LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./first"));
} else {
  LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./second"));
}

class App extends Component {
  render() { return <LazyComponent />; }
}
```

Now, if you run `npm run build:first` and check the bundle you will see that:

- First.tsx and Second.tsx components put to theirs own respective chunks
- Functions we moved out of the common file was respectively inlined into the related chunks.
- Not used functions did not exists in the build

Comment: Had you tried parallelizing multiple entry points? Also, any drawback of building every entry points separately vs using entry points inside webpack?

Comment: @Ashish - nope. We had a common logic on the start, no reason to split it to the different entry points.  Entry points from webpack gives you much better control. However, for applications built with CRA webpack is not an option, unless ejected.